# Running single window service on multiple server in active active mode

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services

In my application I am running a windows service on a Web server. This service calls a single table and selects and update the table as well as insert some record in another table. When this service is deployed on multiple web servers running in an active/active configuration, then it will process records, multiple times and also create duplicate records in a table.

How can I prevent this problem so that my service running on multiple server will process unique records as well as I want that if my one of my server goes down then second server will process all the requests.
I am thinking of some custom queue kind of concept but did not figure out how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implements a sql semaphore, here is some example:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Miscellaneous/2649/

http://blog.udby.com/archives/14